# Python how to put function or method in array while only being called once referenced

Tags: python

If i have this tuple:

```
tuple = (a + 1,'hello','hello2',etc...)
```

and at the start of the program, variable a is 1,
while being 2 later on,
tuple[0] sould return 2 at the start, and 3 at the end.
how do i go about doing this?

should i make it 'a + 1' and use eval()?
don't ask "why i would need this"
or "why am i doing it this way"
because we all know the 'uninformative people on stackoverflow' memes, and i genuinely need to know.

Comment: `eval('a + 1')` won't change `a` to `2`. You'd need `eval('a := a + 1')` to update the value and also return the new value.

Comment: i mean i was going to set a to eval('a + 1') but that works as well!

Comment: BTW, don't use `tuple` as a variable name, it's a built-in class name.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function.

```
a = 1
my_tuple = (lambda x: x + 1, "hello")
a = my_tuple[0](a)
print(a) # prints 2
a = my_tuple[0](a)
print(a) # prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To compliment what @Barmar [has posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72525006/15261315) you could do something like the following using `eval`.

```
a = 1
my_tuple = (lambda: eval('a + 1'), "hello")
print(my_tuple[0]()) # prints 2
a = 2
print(my_tuple[0]()) # prints 3
```